# using [[deprecated]]

Tags: c++, visual-studio, deprecated

I want to deprecate some functions in an old codebase.  My header files look like:

foo.h:

```
class A
{
  [[deprecated]] virtual int F0()=0;
}
```

bar.h:

```
class B: A
{
  [[deprecated]] int F0();
}
```

When I compile this in VS2017, I get a deprecated warning in class `B` because the name was previously deprecated in class `A`.  If I remove the deprecated directive in `B`, I also get the warning for the same reason.  That seems kind of unfair.

What is the right way around this?

Comment: Well, this inheritance means that every `B` is an `A` by nature. If you say on the interface, not to use the method `F0`, then you should not use that function for derived classes too. Imagine, that `A` is part of a library that you cannot control. And with a version update they remove this method.... I would like to receive warnings early on not to use that method.

Answer (score 3):

If a base class method is marked as deprecated, it doesn't matter if an overriding method in a derived class is also marked as deprecated or not. The method is still deprecated in the derived class.

Just like an overriding method doesn't need to use `virtual` explicitly, but the method is still virtual.  The same is true with `[[deprecated]]`, too.

cppreference.com says this:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/deprecated

> A name declared non-deprecated may be redeclared deprecated. **A name declared deprecated cannot be un-deprecated by redeclaring it without this attribute.**